# ng-include with mixed value hard-coded and variables from the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-template, angularjs-ng-include

I want the ng-include to have value like that \'customer\'+{{action}}+\'.html\'

```
.directive('tabContent',function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template:'<div ng-if="view==\'customer\'+{{action}}+\'.html'\" ng-include="\'{{action}}.html\'"></div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.action = attrs.action;
    }
}
```

})

How can I combine in the value ng-include hard-coded values and scope values.
Thanks,
        Omer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ng-include should correct like below.

```
ng-include="action + \'.html\'"></div>',
```

Comment: It is still doesn't work. I'm getting the following exception: 
``Syntax Error: Token 'action' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{action+'.html'}}] starting at [action+'.html'}}].``

Comment: @omer727 sorry that was my bad..look at the edit..interpolation never get work inside the `ng-include`